# How to compile this complex sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have a question about an SQL I want to perform but got no idea on how to write it. Below are the tables with so dummy data:

**Module:**

```
ModuleId (PK auto) ModuleNo   ModuleName
1                  CHI2523    Business
```

**Course:**

```
CourseId (PK auto)  CourseName
1                    Business and Computing
2                    ICT
3                    Sports
```

**Course_Module:**

```
CourseId (PK) ModuleId (PK)
1             1 
2             1
```

**Session:**

```
SessionId (PK auto)  SessionName  ModuleId (FK)
3                    DFRER        1
```

**Student:**

```
StudentId (PK auto)  StudentAlias StudentForename  StudentSurname  CourseId (FK)
1                    u03824       Bill             Murphy          1
2                    u38492       Conrad           Jones           2
3                    u48383       Jane             Peters          1
4                    u34322       Morgan           Gray            2
5                    u39292       Bilal            Tuddy           3
```

**Student_Session:**

```
SessionId (PK)  StudentId (PK)
3               1
3               2
```

What I want the query to be able to find is all of the remaining students that are not currently taking the selected assessment but who are legible to take the assessment.

So to be able to do this we have to:

- Look at what the selected session is by looking up `SessionId` in `Session` Table
- See which module that `SessionId` belongs to by seeing the `ModuleId` in `Session` Table.
- See which courses that `ModuleId` is in by looking up `Course_Module` table
- Look up each student's course by looking at `CourseId` in student table that matches with the `CourseId`'s from the `Course_Module` Table
- Display all students who belongs to the Course where the module is in, but only dislay students who are not currently in the session (or in other words not in the `Session` Table taking the selected `SessionId`.

So if the `SessionId` chosen is 3, then the students it should output are:

```
StudentId (PK auto)  StudentAlias StudentForename  StudentSurname  CourseId (FK)
3                    u48383       Jane             Peters          1
4                    u34322       Morgan           Gray            2
```

This is because:

- `SessionId` 3 belongs to `ModuleId` 1
- `ModuleId` belongs to `CourseId` 1 and 2
- Looking up `CourseId` 1 and 2 there are 4 students who take that course
- But 2 of those students are already taking `SessionId` 3 when looking at `Student_Session` Table, so only display the other 2 students as they are currently not taking the session

My question is how is the query suppose to be written to be able to achieve the example mentioned above? I have made a start on the query but need someone's help to enhance it so it meets with the repuirements of the example above:

```
SELECT s.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname
FROM Session s 
INNER JOIN Module m ON m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId
INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
INNER JOIN Student s ON cm.CourseId = s.CourseId
INNER JOIN Student_Session ss ON s.StudentId = ss.StudentId
WHERE s.SessionId = 3
ORDER BY StudentAlias;
```

I don't know how to check to see which students are/are not legible and then selecting only those students who are legible for taking assessment but who are not currently taking part in assessment

Comment: your question is well explained. `:D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  e.*
FROM    Session a
        INNER JOIN Module b
            ON a.ModuleID = b.ModuleID
        INNER JOIN Course_Module c
            ON b.ModuleID = c.ModuleID
        INNER JOIN Course d
            ON c.CourseID = d.CourseID
        INNER JOIN Student e
            ON d.CourseID = e.CourseID
        LEFT JOIN Student_Session f
            ON f.sessionID = a.SessionID AND
                f.studentID = e.studentID
WHERE   a.SessionID = 3 AND
        f.studentID IS NULL
ORDER   BY e.STUDENTALIAS
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c068/8)

Comment: That is fantastic, thank you very much JW, best answer :) I will give you an upvote once I reach 15 reputation points

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname
FROM Session s 
INNER JOIN Module m ON m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId
INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
INNER JOIN Student s ON cm.CourseId = s.CourseId
LEFT OUITER JOIN Student_Session ss ON s.StudentId = ss.StudentId AND s.SessionId = 3
WHERE s.SessionId = 3
AND ss.SessionID IS NULL
ORDER BY StudentAlias;
```

The left outer join allows you to find out who is in Student_session and who is not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well aserna01

Answer (score 0):

I did not had the time to create some test database out of your data, but I hope my code give you some hints, how to reach your goal.

You should not use INNER JOINs without urge. They are not good for request performance and will produce many duplicates where you don't want them.

Maybe you should read this for a better understanding: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

```
SELECT s.* FROM Student AS s 

# JOIN STUDENT SESSION
LEFT JOIN Student_Session AS ss
ON (ss.StudentId = s.StudentId AND ss.SessionId = 3)

# JOIN COURSE
LEFT JOIN Course_Module AS cm
ON s.CourseId = cm.CourseId

LEFT JOIN Session AS se 
ON (cm.ModuleId = se.ModuleId AND se.SessionId = 3)

WHERE se.SessionId IS NOT NULL
AND ss.SessionId IS NULL

ORDER BY StudentAlias;
```